# Finding letters just beyond a space in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to print the first letters of the first three words of a sentence, but in the `d4 = y.find(" ", d3)` part, the program doesn't identify it as an integer, and if I convert it to an integer, it causes an error because I'm in base 10.

How do I solve the problem?

```
y = raw_input("Please type in a sentence consisting three to four words.: ")
d1 = y[0]
d2 = y.find(" ")
d3 = y[d2+1]
d4 = y.find(" ", d3)
d5 = y[d4+1]
print d1+d3+d5
```

Comment: "i'm trying to print the first three letter of a sentence" - did you mean: I'm trying to print the first letter of each one of the first three words in a sentence ?

Comment: You get an error in `d4 = y.find(" ", d3)` because the find method expects an index as second argument, but you pass a character.

Answer (score 2):

From your code it looks like you're trying to print the initials of the first three words in a sentence. Remember, `split()` returns an array:

```
y = "one two three four"
y = y.split(" ")
print y[0][0],y[1][0],y[2][0]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
o t t
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this through split function.

```
y = raw_input("Please type in a sentence consisting three to four words.: ")
print ''.join([i[0] for i in y.split()])
```

Output:

```
$ python f.py
Please type in a sentence consisting three to four words.: foo bar foobar
fbf
```

Comment: Nice! the only issue is that it'll print *all* the initials of the input - instead of the initials of the first three words only.